# Fpdf html to pdf - css not working

Tags: php, css, fpdf

I am trying to convert html to pdf using fpdf. But styles are not working with it. Please suggest me how can I use style internally in fpdf.

I use `<style>` tag for including style.

Comment: not working you say, well well that's no good.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php?rq=1